# Is there any follow button for google plus collections?

Tags: google-plus

I like to know if there is a follow button code for google plus collections.
So people can directly follow each one of my collections.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a follow button for a collection. The closest is the [follow button for a user](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/).